# Install package depending on OS

Tags: centos, debian, composer-php

We have been testing with Platform.sh this weekend, which uses `debian` as its OS.  The deployment of the application was easy, until we started testing some of the core functionalities like creating a PDF.

The PDF is generated using `wkhtmltopdf`, which has different binaries depending on OS. Our own platform consists of CentOS7 machines, so we let composer install the Centos7 specific package: https://github.com/rvanlaak/wkhtmltopdf-amd64-centos7 For Debian this package is needed: https://github.com/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64

So basically the problem is the inconsistency in plaform. Saw that composer allows you to define specific versions for PHP and extensions, but [`config.platform`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform) unfortunately can not solve this problem.

Unfortunately the following hooks did resolve into a deployment error too:

```
composer remove rvanlaak/wkhtmltopdf-amd64-centos7 --no-update
composer require h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64:~0.12 --no-update
composer update
```

As we can not choose the OS on platform.sh, how can we let composer check for a specific OS?

Comment: To what error did your manual steps lead during deployment?

Comment: That's a bit hard to debug at platform.sh because of the read-only filesystem. The log output only shows `returned non-zero exit status 1` right after the `composer update`.

Comment: Ah well, `composer remove` and `composer require` will update your `composer.json` file which will fail on a read-only filesystem. Looks like you will have to modify the file before deploying it to platform.sh.

Comment: These commands happen during the build hook before the package is beamed to it's final location, so at that moment it should still be writable. But to stay with composer, as I understand it won't be possible to do a check for the OS via composer? This should be something that the bundle should do while symlinking the binary?

Comment: Another update: removing the `--no-update` parameters from the hooks, and the `clearCache` and `installAssets` command from the composer.json `post-update-cmd` did solve this. The Platform.sh builder does not have a relationship with the database yet, and somehow these two commands require the database, so we can only execute these two commands in the `deploy` hooks.

Comment: I would investigate that on a local system where you close the database connection. It seems like you have some services that do more work than necessary in their constructor requiring a database (Doctrine?) connection.

Comment: Did hunt this down to one of the bundles that require a database connection during initialization. Also need to deactivate all configuration blocks to debug this a bit further, so that will take some time.